# Hibernate OneToMany list empty

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My entities:

Customer.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer", schema = "pbis", catalog = "feivel")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "customerid")
    private long id;
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Invoice> invoices;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Receipt> receipts;
}
```

Invoice.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="invoice", schema = "pbis", catalog = "feivel")
public class Invoice {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "invoicenumber")
    private long invoiceNumber;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customerid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Customer customer;
}
```

Receipt.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "receipts", schema = "pbis", catalog = "feivel")
public class Receipt {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ReceiptId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customerid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Customer customer;
```

A simple Hibernate Query

```
SELECT c FROM Customer WHERE c.id = :id
```

I get the correct size of `c.getInvoices().size();`
But `c.getReceipts().size();` returns zero

When I use eclipselink with the same query, I get the correct size of both receipts and invoices.

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("eclipselink");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

javax.persistence.Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.id = :id");
q.setParameter("id", Long.valueOf(event.getText()));
```

Using a Criteria with ResultTransformer also gives me the correct receipts.size

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Customer.class);
c.add(Restrictions.eq("id", Long.valueOf(event.getText())));
c.setFetchMode("receipts", FetchMode.JOIN);
c.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
for (Object o : c.list()) {
    Customer r = (Customer) o;
    System.out.println(r.getReceipts().size());
}
```

Using `SELECT r FROM Receipt WHERE r.customer.id = :id`, I get the correct `r.getCustomer()` but the receipts-set is still empty.

So .. where is my mapping wron or my thinking?

Thank you

Comment: Since the mapping is `LAZY` I believe you must seeing two extra select queries getting fired when you call `c.getInvoices().size();` and `c.getReceipts().size();` respectively. Can you check what is query that is getting fired for `receipts`. For this, do enable `show_sql` property.

Comment: Try add `@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)` or `@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)` to `@OneToMany` annotations.

Comment: This is a long shot, but try to rename the customer attribute in one of your classes and also their respective mappedBy value ...

Comment: @Beig few things - You may want to remove `insertable  & updatable-false` and `CascadeType.ALL` on `invoices` variable and try. First change allows you to populate the `customer` column in DB while saving the records. And second one allows to save `invoices` while saving `customer` record. Beyond that I don't see any issues with mapping.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I tried all your suggestion, and looking at the sql log from hibernate pointed me in the right direction.
Insertable & Updateable to false is right because I can't edit the tables (I get those from our mother company)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the hibernate sql log I found out that an additional @ManyToOne mapping in the Receipt Entity was at fault.

I added optional = true to the mapping and now I get the correct recipe-set size.

Although I think it should've worked without it, because the Java doc says that optional is defaulted to true.